# How to search file in directory using rust DirEntry?

Tags: rust

im making a program where user will input the filename that has to be searched in directory so when im using DirEntry to get path im getting a error like this

```
mismatched types
expected reference `&DirEntry`
   found reference `&String`
```

the code is

```
pub fn search_file(filepath : &String) -> Result<&Path,(&str, std::io::Error)>{
    let mut filename = String::new();
    println!("enter your filename to be searched");
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut filename).expect("failed to read input");

    let ans = DirEntry::path(&filename).as_path();
    Ok(ans)
}
```

can someone help me to rectify this program so it can successfully search the file in dir and return the path

Comment: Well, `.path()` is a method of `DirEntry` that takes `&self`, [as you can see in the doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.DirEntry.html#method.path)... so you're definitely using it incorrectly. There is literally an example in the doc that iterates over each `DirEntry` in the current folder (`"."`), you can use that as a base.

Comment: you can use Path and PathBuf

Answer (score 0):

`DirEntry` is a *result* of `read_dir`: when you traverse a directory, you iterate directory entries.

You can't *create* a direntry, it's a thing you get from an iteration. Not to mention you don't need to iterate anything, a directory is essentially an associative array, if you have a directory and a filename you can just check if the file exists in the directory:

```rust
let dir = Path::new(&filepath);
let candidate = dir.join(&filename);
if candidate.exists() {
   Ok(candidate)
} else {
    todo!()
}
```